# Создание полосы состояния загрузки

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как можно создать полосу загрузки какого-нибуть файла на сервер. Например загрузка аватара, когда юзер пытаеться его загрузить то показываеться полоса состояния (1% - 100%). Как ее можно создать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для аватара в этом нет смысла =) Он маленький и загрузится быстро...

А вообще, много плагинов для jQuery, например, кои делают это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полоса загрузки она же по "научному" statusbar или progressbar. Введите в гугл progressbar jquery и выбирайте. По первой ссылке вроде был не плохой плагин http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryProgressBar. Рекомендую также разобраться с http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Answer (score 1):

Прогресс не стоит на месте )))
https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Answer (score 0):

На jQuery, основа которого jаvasript, нет возможности сканировать размер переданной части файла, яваскрипт нужен для обработки событий и простых вычислений в браузере. Есть уйма решений на технологии flash, называются приблизительно так "flash download bar", ещё есть технология java, на ней вроде тоже реализована эта возможность, но требуется установка у пользователя приличного размера плагина виртуальной java-машины; для отображения флеша необходимая примочка уже имеется в новых браузерах.